# mysql - not able to add foreign key constraint after changing column name

Tags: mysql

I was changing column name of a column having foreign key constraint, i have done this by

```
ALTER TABLE `city_details` DROP FOREIGN KEY `tb_city_details_ibfk_1`;

ALTER TABLE `city_details` CHANGE `city_state_id` `city_district_id` int(8) NOT NULL AFTER `city_name`;
```

now while adding constraint back i'm getting error

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`#sql-39a8_23`, CONSTRAINT `city_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`city_district_id`) REFERENCES `district_details` (`district_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

i have used this query to add constraint

```
 ALTER TABLE `city_details` ADD CONSTRAINT `city_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`city_district_id`) REFERENCES `district_details`(`district_id`)  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

SHOW CREATE TABLE city_details

CREATE TABLE `city_details` (
 `city_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `city_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `city_district_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
 KEY `city_state_id` (`city_district_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue district_details table was empty but city_details table had few values, after adding values to district_details it is working fine